# UEC - Unable to SSH into instance, asks for password

Tags: 10.04, ssh, cloud, uec

I am attempting to set up a private cloud using Ubuntu 10.04.4 Server. I am following the tutorial at http://cssoss.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/eucabook-v1-1/ . All steps go on perfectly apart from that I am unable to SSH into the running instances. I have created the instance using a public key and try to SSH into instance using the private key. However it asks for password. I am able to ping the instance though. I have tried using both the pre-built images from the store as well as custom built images.

Several people seem to have the same problem but there does not seem to be any working solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ssh -i mykey.priv ubuntu@ipaddress-of-instance
```

This will not ask any password to enter.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the "verbose" in ssh, which shows deugging messages : `ssh -v` .  This may show you the problem right away.

Try regenerating the key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, and re-copying it to the server.  That's worked for me when ssh is complaining about the key type (in verbose mode) and failing passwordless login.

Finally, check the permissions of your `.ssh` directory to make sure they are not too permissive.